# How do I focus on a form after entering a textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm not sure if focus is the right word but I have an on key up event on my form that will open a new form and close the current form, however after i enter a textbox or other such object i can't re select the form to be able to activate the key up event

This is code a I am using currently when i click on my form, to try select my currently open form however it does not close the current form when i active the key up event, when i do it this way

```
private void frmLevel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.BackColor = GlobalClass.BG;
   frmLevel1 lvl1 = new frmLevel1();
   lvl1.Select();
}
```

Comment: You can only have the Focus on one GUI Element, and hte whole Window is just such a Element. While it is often forgotten, Windows does still support Keyboard only/mouseless control. How would the cursor move in your case?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean, when the form loads i am currently not in any textbox and my pressing the keyboard doesn't interact with anything but events i have for key presses on the form. After i enter a text box my key presses no longer interact with events on my formonly the textbox. I want to be able to click the background of my form and get back to the first stage. sorry if i have worded this horribly i am still not to familiar with the correct words to use

Comment: What display technology are you using? Windows Forms? WPF/UWP? ASP.NET? Other?

Comment: Windows forms on visual studio

Comment: In WPF you would have things like Routing and Tunneling events to work with. I think in Windows Forms you have to register the Key Press Events on every element, from the Form to the Textbox. Unless there is some other way to make Keypresses in WinForms I am not aware off. In any cases I added the WinForms tag.

Comment: thanks for the help

Comment: See: [ProcessCmdKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey). With this override (Form class), you can receive key events from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but you have a few different questions. I hope it helps.

```
// Button click event
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Focus on textbox
    this.ActiveControl = textBox1;
}

// Form load event
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Focus on textbox
    this.ActiveControl = textBox1;
}

// Close the current form and open another one. Use any event what you want
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Form2 frm = new Form2())
    {
        // Hide the current form. If you close it it will dispose of all further events
        this.Hide();

        // Open the new form
        frm.Show();

        // Close the current form
        this.Close();
    }
}
```